# Python 3: create a list of possible ip addresses from a CIDR notation

Tags: python, subnet, cidr

I have been handed the task of creating a function in python (3.1) that will take a CIDR notation and return the list of possible ip addresses.  I have looked around python.org and found this:
http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/ipaddr.html

but i haven't seen anything that will fill this need... I would be very grateful for any assistance anyone cares to kick my way. thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: Might want to go back and accept some answers to your questions if they were helpful...

Comment: I have used IPy (http://c0re.23.nu/c0de/IPy/) on Python 2.x, and now am in the process of porting it to Python 3.  I will post a link as an answer once I am done.

Comment: @AJ: IPy is also a good choice, but I recommended netaddr because I like it better. :)

Comment: Update:  I have submitted a new version of IPy to its current maintainer for review.  Given the holidays, I'm not sure when this will be released, but I will post a link once it is.

Answer (score 79):

In Python 3 as simple as

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> [str(ip) for ip in ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.0.2.0/28')]
['192.0.2.0', '192.0.2.1', '192.0.2.2',
'192.0.2.3', '192.0.2.4', '192.0.2.5',
'192.0.2.6', '192.0.2.7', '192.0.2.8',
'192.0.2.9', '192.0.2.10', '192.0.2.11',
'192.0.2.12', '192.0.2.13', '192.0.2.14',
'192.0.2.15']
```

Comment: this works directly on the python3 terminal but how about in a .py file??

Comment: @Tony The first two lines of this answer can go into a .py file, minus the >>> at the head of each line.  In the second line, you should assign the list to a variable which you can then view or do other operations on.  If you put [str(ip) for ip in ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.0.2.0/28')] as-is into a file and then run it, there will be no output.  But assign it to a variable like ip_list = [str(ip) for ip in ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.0.2.0/28')], then you can print(ip_list) for example to see the list.

Comment: Please note that this answer provides a list of addresses which include both the network address (192.0.2.0) and the broadcast address (192.0.2.15) which are not usable for assigning to a host. This is correct behavior for Python, but could lead to confusion with other stakeholders if they are not familiar with networking.

Answer (score 51):

If you aren't married to using the built-in module, there is a project called [netaddr](http://code.google.com/p/netaddr/) that is the best module I have used for working with IP networks.

Have a look at the [IP Tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/netaddr/wiki/IPTutorial) which illustrates how easy it is working with networks and discerning their IPs.  Simple example:

```
>>> from netaddr import IPNetwork
>>> for ip in IPNetwork('192.0.2.0/23'):
...    print '%s' % ip
...
192.0.2.0
192.0.2.1
192.0.2.2
192.0.2.3
...
192.0.3.252
192.0.3.253
192.0.3.254
192.0.3.255
```

Comment: interesting but how is the mapping done? is there a deterministic formula that maps the CIDR networks to the single IP addresses? Or one needs a database to do the mapping?

Answer (score 15):

I would prefer to do a little math rather than to install an external module, no one has the same taste with me?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# python cidr.py 192.168.1.1/24

import sys, struct, socket

(ip, cidr) = sys.argv[1].split('/')
cidr = int(cidr) 
host_bits = 32 - cidr
i = struct.unpack('>I', socket.inet_aton(ip))[0] # note the endianness
start = (i >> host_bits) << host_bits # clear the host bits
end = start | ((1 << host_bits) - 1)

# excludes the first and last address in the subnet
for i in range(start, end):
    print(socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('>I',i)))
```

Comment: Note that this excludes the broadcast address, which may or may not be what you want. Remove the `-1` when computing "end" to include it.

Comment: @Peter, removing the `-1` only works on even IP addresses (e.g. where the 4th octet ends in an even number). Add `end += 1` as the line just after subtracting 1.

Comment: @jfky could you please explain this math?

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out [`iptools`](http://code.google.com/p/python-iptools/)? It seems to be a fairly good fit.

Comment: Given that it seems to not support Python 2.3, it would probably require at least a nominal amount of effort to support Python 3.1.

Comment: I've updated iptools to support Python 2.3, 2.5, 2.6 and 3.1.

Answer (score 2):

We can get this by using ipaddress lib of Python if you are not interested in playing with python logics. Else above solutions are enough.

```
import ipaddress
  
def get_ip_from_subnet(ip_subnet):

    ips= ipaddress.ip_network(ip_subnet)
    ip_list=[str(ip) for ip in ips]
    return ip_list

ip_subnet= "192.168.2.0/24"
print(get_ip_from_subnet(ip_subnet))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not in the documentation, but browsing the source suggests that `ipaddr` implements `__iter__` and `iterhosts`, which is exactly what you want.

---

Err, nevermind.

1. It looks like `ipaddr.py` was added to stdlib in 3.1 beta, but removed by 3.1 rc.
2. I was looking at the sources from the original [ipaddr.py](http://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/), which seems to have evolved separately from the copy at python.org.

You could just bundle the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will generate range of IPs on providing IP and subnet. Expand the CIDR notation like(255.255.255.0)

```
from netaddr import *

def getFirstIp(ipAddress,subnet):
  ipBin = IPNetwork(ipAddress).ip.bits().split('.')
  subBin = IPNetwork(subnet).ip.bits().split('.')
  zipped = zip(ipBin,subBin)
  netIdList = []
  for octets in zipped:
    netIdList.append(''.join(str(b) for b in (map((lambda x: int(x[0])*int(x[1])),zip(list(octets[0]),list(octets[1]))))))
  firstIp = ''
  firstIp = '.'.join(str(int(oct,2)) for oct in netIdList)
  return firstIp


def getLastIp(ipAddress,subnet):
  ipBin = IPNetwork(ipAddress).ip.bits().split('.')
  subBin = IPNetwork(subnet).ip.bits().split('.')
  #print ipBin
  #print subBin
  revsubBin = []
  for octets in subBin:
    revB = ''.join('1' if(b == '0') else '0' for b in octets)
    revsubBin.append(revB)
  zipped = zip(ipBin,revsubBin)
  netIdList = []
  for octets in zipped:
    netIdList.append(''.join(str(b) for b in (map((lambda x: 0 if(int(x[0]) == 0 and int(x[1]) == 0) else 1),zip(list(octets[0]),list(octets[1]))))))
  #print netIdList
  lastIp = ''
  lastIp = '.'.join(str(int(oct,2)) for oct in netIdList)
  return lastIp

def getRangeOfIps(firstIp,lastIp):
  start= int(IPAddress(firstIp))
  end = int(IPAddress(lastIp))
  ipList = []
  for ip in range(start,end+1):
    ipList.append(str(IPAddress(ip)))
  return ipList

def manipulateIP():
 firstIp = getFirstIp(ipAddress,subnet)
 lastIp = getLastIp(ipAddress,subnet)
 ipList = getRangeOfIps(firstIp,lastIp)  
 print ipList
```

Answer (score -3):

## Generate all Public IP Addresses given a CIDR

> https://github.com/stephenlb/geo-ip will generate a list of Valid IP Public Addresses including Localities.

**`'1.0.0.0/8'` to `'191.0.0.0/8'`** are the valid public IP Address range exclusive of the reserved Private IP Addresses.

## IP Generator

Generates a JSON dump of IP Addresses and associated Geo information.
Note that the valid public IP Address range is
from `'1.0.0.0/8'` to `'191.0.0.0/8'` excluding the reserved
Private IP Address ranges shown lower down in this readme.

```sh
docker build -t geo-ip .
docker run -e IPRANGE='54.0.0.0/30' geo-ip               ## a few IPs
docker run -e IPRANGE='54.0.0.0/26' geo-ip               ## a few more IPs
docker run -e IPRANGE='54.0.0.0/16' geo-ip               ## a lot more IPs
docker run -e IPRANGE='0.0.0.0/0'   geo-ip               ## ALL IPs ( slooooowwwwww )
docker run -e IPRANGE='0.0.0.0/0'   geo-ip > geo-ip.json ## ALL IPs saved to JSON File
docker run geo-ip
```

A little faster option for scanning all valid public addresses:

```sh
for i in $(seq 1 191); do \
    docker run -e IPRANGE="$i.0.0.0/8" geo-ip; \
    sleep 1; \ 
done
```

This prints less than *4,228,250,625* JSON lines to STDOUT.
Here is an example of one of the lines:

```
{"city": "Palo Alto", "ip": "0.0.0.0", "longitude": -122.1274,
 "continent": "North America", "continent_code": "NA",
 "state": "California", "country": "United States", "latitude": 37.418,
 "iso_code": "US", "state_code": "CA", "aso": "PubNub",
 "asn": "11404", "zip_code": "94107"}
```

### Private and Reserved IP Range

The dockerfile in the repo above will exclude non-usable IP addresses
following the guide from the wikipedia article:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses

### MaxMind Geo IP

The dockerfile imports a free public Database provided by https://www.maxmind.com/en/home