# Filter IPs coming from AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pandas, ip

I have a list of IPs and I want to filter out the IPs that come from AWS. Fortunately, AWS publishes a [list](https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json) of their IPs. That list is in a JSON format, so I converted it to a [CSV](https://json-csv.com/c/ru5L). I then filtered my IP addresses using `my_ip = my_ip[~my_ip['col'].isin(amazon_ips['col'])]`.

Unfortunately, I think that the list is for ranges of IPs, rather than actually containing each IP that an AWS request could have come from. How can I correct for this?

Comment: please share json structure of the aws ips you are storing. Without that no one will be able to guesswhat you are trying to achieve

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I included a link to the JSON in the original post. Here it is again https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list you are getting contains IP Ranges using [CIDR Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing).

You could programmatically determine the individual IP addresses from a CIDR Block, if required: [Python 3: create a list of possible ip addresses from a CIDR notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942160/python-3-create-a-list-of-possible-ip-addresses-from-a-cidr-notation)