# How to know which IP is after a certain number of IPs

Tags: python, ipv4, delegation

Im working on RIPE Delegation Stats

and each line in the file is in the following format:

```
registry|cc|type|start|value|date|status[|extensions...]
```

where start and value means the following:

```
start: This is the IPv4 'first address' of the range.

value: In the case of IPv4 address the count of hosts for this range. This count does not have to represent a CIDR range.
```

examples for start and value:

```
196.4.163.0|768

41.74.0.0|4096

195.35.104.64|192 

198.54.38.0|1536

216.252.155.0|256

141.226.144.0|10240 

93.242.1.0|20224 

193.53.200.0|11520
```

How can I know which IP to end up with?

Thank you so much!

--- Update ----

I figured out how to solve this problem.

convert the first IP to a decimal number then add the value to it then convert back to ip < like that I will get both start and end IP for the range

Comment: Many of the address ranges can not be converted to CIDR notation. Only networks the size of 2^n and and starting at multiple of it can be.

Answer (score 0):

`ipcalc`, `sipcalc`, or just [pure Bash](https://serverfault.com/a/682849) will do the trick.

For more answers, including with examples, see: https://serverfault.com/q/54981

As for Python, you can just use the builtin https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html or just `struct` and `socket` builtins https://stackoverflow.com/a/44043448